# React Native: "error Cannot start server in new window because no terminal app was specified"

Tags: windows, react-native, microsoft-metro

After updating to React Native v73.1, I'm getting the below error when trying to run the app in Windows:

> error Cannot start server in new window because no terminal app was specified.

How can I fix it?

On a Mac machine, there aren't any issues. Only Windows is facing this issue.

Comment: Are you facing this issue in the VS Code or Terminal?

Comment: both place facing same issues

Comment: new terminal run the "npm start" and open second new terminal/powershell to execute command in "npx react-native run-android --mode=release".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had the same issue using React Native 0.73.1, when I had to run release mode.

In the case of debug mode, you can simply use `npm start` and then `a`.

However, if you want to run release mode, use `npm start` to run Metro, open a new terminal and execute `npx react-native run-android --mode=release`.

This worked in my case.

Comment: is their any way to fix it and make it work like it was

Comment: npx react-native run-android --terminal powershell

Comment: i don't think this should be count as answer, just  add "--terminal <your terminal > after "npx react-native run-androd".   your terminal could be "cmd.exe", "powershell.exe" or "bash" etc, depends your enviroment. as @naveedahmed commented above.

Answer (score 11):

You can try to use the "npm run start" script.

[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cPpIE.png)

Comment: Please review *[Why not upload images of code/errors when asking a question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/)* (e.g., *"Images should only be used to illustrate problems that* ***can't be made clear in any other way,*** *such as to provide screenshots of a user interface."*) and [do the right thing](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77689809/edit) (it covers answers as well). Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 9):

It looks like Metro has lost support for [Windows Terminal](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Terminal) and only allows a Bash terminal. I had to launch it once in [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway), and keep the Metro window open, before being able to launch React Native in Windows Terminal.

It seems there isn't much we can do, aside from waiting for React Native and Metro to fix it.

I have created an issue there: *[Metro on Windows: Cannot start server in new window because no terminal app was specified #1160](https://github.com/facebook/metro/issues/1160)*

[image]

Answer (score 6):

It was a bug introduced in the latest [React Native CLI](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli).
I already pushed [a fix for that](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/pull/2236), and the upcoming React Native CLI should work fine.

Until then, you can use:

```
npm run start
```

And then press <kbd>A</kbd> to start the Android build.

Answer (score 1):

Please try => **"npx react-native start"** script.

Answer (score 1):

As referenced in [this issue](https://github.com/react-native-community/cli/issues/2219), there is a new --terminal flag where you pass the path to the terminal you want to open. It's still not ideal but it works. For example:

```
react-native run-android --active-arch-only --mode=devDebug --terminal='C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe'
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this code. It will work.

```
npm run start
```

Answer (score 0):

If you would like to use [Yarn](https://yarnpkg.com/), you can run this on your project folder with [Git Bash](https://superuser.com/questions/1053633/what-is-git-bash-for-windows-anyway), which then opens Windows Terminal on the side.

```
yarn android
```

***Note***: running this in Windows Terminal will not work!