# react-native: 0.73.2 upgrade now causing cannot locate tasks

Tags: android, react-native, visual-studio-code

We are banging our head over here.  We updated to React Native 0.73.2 and keep getting the following errors below.  Our master app still works fine with the older version but this just cant get pass this error on yarn start.  We are on Windows also in Code.

```
* What went wrong:
Cannot locate tasks that match 'app:installDebug' as task 'installDebug' is ambiguous in project ':app'. Candidates are: 'installComexposure585Debug', 'installComexposure585DebugAndroidTest', 'installExposure0Debug', 'installExposure0DebugAndroidTest', 'installExposure511Debug', 'installExposure511DebugAndroidTest', 'installExposure8Debug', 'installExposure8DebugAndroidTest'.
```

**build.gradle**

```
productFlavors {
    exposure0 {
        applicationId project.env.get("ANDROID_APP_ID")
        resValue "string", "APP_LABEL", project.env.get("APP_LABEL")
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.exposure"
    }
    exposure8 {
        applicationId project.env.get("ANDROID_APP_ID")
        resValue "string", "APP_LABEL", project.env.get("APP_LABEL")
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.exposure"
    }
exposure511 {
        applicationId project.env.get("ANDROID_APP_ID")
        resValue "string", "APP_LABEL", project.env.get("APP_LABEL")
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.exposure"
    }
    comexposure585 {
        applicationId project.env.get("ANDROID_APP_ID")
        resValue "string", "APP_LABEL", project.env.get("APP_LABEL")
        resValue "string", "build_config_package", "com.exposure"
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [full changelog](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/main/CHANGELOG.md) for React Native 0.73.2.

In here, among a few of the breaking changes mentioned, the React Native Android Gradle Plugin (NAGP) [had flavor support added](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/commit/8ad86c70b6341f2e8bd40f5ba86f1a0d451008b0).

There are essentially two dimensions to gradle builds w/ Android Gradle.

1. Build variants - Like `debug` and `release`. Usually intended to differentiate configurations relevant to this.
2. Product flavors - Like `comexposure585` or `exposure0` in your case. Usually intended to differentiate different featuresets you may build with.

Android Gradle will create a build variant, `debug` for debugging without explicitly being told to. For an app with only one flavor, that task would be `app:installDebug`.

Now that NAGP has flavor support, these will instead generate as:
`app:install<FlavorName>Debug`, `app:install<FlavorName>Release`, etc, for every flavor. Due to the upgrade, your build file now has these flavors.

Based on the error, you need to invoke the build with: `react-native run-android --mode comexposure585Debug`, for example, if you wanted to build the `comexposure585` flavor with the `debug` build variant.

Hopefully this helps.

Comment: `error: unknown option '--variant`

Comment: This built and installed if I removed the entire product flavors section, kinda like you said.   `--variant` has been deprecated for `--mode`.  `yarn react-native run-android --mode exposure0Debug` did work but only when running in bash, as there seems to be a bug in powershell for windows with this version.  If you update your answer to `--mode` Ill mark it as answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77684266/react-native-error-cannot-start-server-in-new-window-because-no-terminal-app-w

Comment: Important to note: I don't know what the specific use case for those flavors was. It is possible that depending on functionality certain mobile manufacturers will have their own quirks or outright mutually exclusive solutions for some problems like push notifications. A notorious example of this is Huawei. I would ensure that those flavors weren't distributions for such cases. You may have that covered already but it is worth noting, would not want deleting flavors to lead to manufacturer-specific issues that aren't caught in tests

Answer (score 0):

i just used this and its work for me

yarn react-native run-android --mode release

Comment: We have multiple flavors